# What are good Buddhist Blogs / articles sites / resource sites out there?

Tags: reference-request

Perhaps we can maintain a collection of Buddhist blogs which might be of interest for many.

Comment: Obliviously there are less good blog and valued Upasaka Dharmasena started , as it looks like, with a sample, although its layout and quality in regard of literary aspects look quite nice. Most blogs are merely a source of doubt and seldom one comes across of one which is in devotion of Buddha, Dhamma, Sangha. Furthermore, as far Atma has observed, are those blogs independent if the maintainer is a layperson or monastic person, hardly censured and seldom have other intentions aside of certain politic. So Upasakas Dharmasenas question is quite a good one. May there follow good answers.

Comment: Please post answers instead of comments. If you follow the format of existing answers, it will be a) a link to the blog b) a sentence which says why you like it and/or what topic[s] it writes about.

Comment: (do we have a tag called "big-list" and the "community-wiki"-function? In the mathematics SE this constructs exist and are applied)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms There isn't a tag but (based on this help page, [How do I search?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)) the following search finds all our CW topics: "[wiki:1 is:question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+is%3Aquestion)".

Answer (score 1):

There is [Berzin Archives](http://www.berzinarchives.com/web/en/index.html). Although I am not familiar with the whole of it, when it comes to Tibetan Buddhism, it is quiet trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy the blog [Theravadin Blog](http://www.theravadin.org)

I like the fact that it contains a lot of discussion around pali words and a lot of advice on meditation.

Enjoy!

Comment: A lot of rupa. Anyway, Does Mrs UrsulRosu knows who is running the blog? Seems to be a Russian Lay person who had studied in Germany/Austria but not much info about the publisher.

Comment: @SamanaJohann Indeed, not much info about the publisher. I do not know who runs the blog, where is he from, what kind of arrow, what poison, from what clan, what the bow string is made from :)

Comment: Good Dhammic answer. Sadhu! But don't forget, sometimes its good to know what is the remove of on arrow and what is an arrow rain. If somebody would tell somebody enjoying sensuality, he/she would answer in the same way. "I am not interested where my pleasure comes from and what it costs and causes for others, I am here to enjoy". So in regard of Dhamma, remembering the Kalamas asking about whom to follow, the live and tendency of the giver was the main place for discrimination. Its good, especially if not knowing the heartwood, to observe the giver of Dhamma and his dependencies well.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten a lot from Ken McLeod's "[Unfettered Mind](http://www.unfetteredmind.org/)", especially the podcasts (in the "Teachings & Writings" menu, drill down into "Podcasts").  I also appreciate his approach to translation.

Answer (score 0):

I have long liked http://sdhammika.blogspot.com but in the last time he does not write too often, so I'm not really "up-to-date" with it..

Comment: [He looks quite well...](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-GsDgoM0JfWQ/VntHdTsLpnI/AAAAAAAAF7I/eoYOlYa2GkE/s400/DSCN2911.JPG)

Answer (score 0):

I came across a well referenced blog which seems to have merit in par with a paper or article. [Just A Little Dust](http://justalittledust.com/blog/).

Also though not a the site [The Dharmafarers](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/) has a lot of articles and well researched Sutta translations.